# VS Code - command 'save-as-root.saveFile' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I needed to install Save As Root to my VS Code so I could save my file. The sysadmin is going to change the folder permission so I can save using VS Code without Save As Root, as a preferred way of saving files. So I uninstalled the extension Save as Root, but VS Code keeps prompting the message 'command 'save-as-root.saveFile' not found. I have restarted vs Code but in vain.
How do i uninstall Save As Root properly.

Comment: any more information in the various output channels of the output panel?

Comment: I checked at the output panel but nothing related to save-as-root.saveFile not found

Answer (score 0):

Check "File -> Preferences -> Profiles (Default) -> Show Profile Contents". A keybindings.json containing keyboard shorcuts should be listed with the following content:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+s",
    "command": "save-as-root.saveFile"
  }
]
```

Remove the entry and the message should disappear. It did the trick for me.